# Selenium - How to find and click element via xpath when page is rendered via javascript

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, xpath

**Problem:**
I am trying to find an element and then click it via xpath using selenium and python, on a web page that is rendered with JavaScript.  The xpath has been confirmed to be correct, the issue is that the html isn't fully rendering due to only seeing the javascript "top level" (i think that's the right term).

I have seen methods of finding the full html code and saving it as a string, but that is not clickable via selenium

**What I Am Looking For:**
A method to just render all the javascript code, so that I can access the html elements I am looking for.

**Code Would Look Like:**

```
browser.render_javascript()
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Budget & Cost Management']/../preceding-sibling::img[2]").click()
```

Currently if I try to find the xpath above, it says it doesn't exist. However, if I inspect the page and search this xpath, it takes me right to the element. Obviously, selenium isn't seeing this element though because it isn't available to it (not rendered or executed, not sure which is the correct term).

I have also tried to just wait 30 seconds before searching for this element, but it doesn't look like any amount of time will render the page to selenium.

Is this possible? What kind of workarounds are available?

Comment: Check if there any iframe present ??

Comment: What if there were?

Comment: You needed it to switch first before accessing the element.

Comment: Thank you. Any idea on how I would go about that? It doesn't seem like any amount of waiting will make a difference.

Comment: can you share your url or html of the page source?